# Adapter design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am referring to the book *Design Patterns For Dummies* to learn about design patterns.  I wrote an adapter design pattern, as mentioned in the book.  Is it proper or does it need some modification?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

class AceInterface
{
public:
    virtual void setName(string n) = 0;
    virtual string getName() = 0;
};

class Aceclass : public AceInterface
{ 
    string name;
public:
    void setName(string n){
        name = n;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
};

class AcmeInterface
{
public:
    virtual void setFirstName(string fn) = 0;
    virtual void setLastName(string ln) = 0;
    virtual string getFirstName() = 0;
    virtual string getLastName() = 0;
};

class Acmeclass :public AcmeInterface
{
    string First_name;
    string Last_name;
public:
    void setFirstName(string fn) {
        First_name = fn;
    }
    void setLastName(string ln) {
        Last_name = ln;
    }
    string getFirstName(){
        return First_name;
    }
    string getLastName(){
        return Last_name;
    }
};

class AcetoAcmeAdapter:public AcmeInterface
{
    Aceclass aceObject;
    string First_name;
    string Last_name;
public:
    AcetoAcmeAdapter(Aceclass a) {
        aceObject = a;
        istringstream iss(aceObject.getName());
        iss >> First_name ;
        iss >> Last_name;
    }
    void setFirstName(string fn) {
        First_name = fn;
    }
    void setLastName(string ln) {
        Last_name = ln;
    }
    string getFirstName(){
        return First_name;
    }
    string getLastName(){
        return Last_name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Aceclass aceobj;

    aceobj.setName("Mohandas Gandhi");

    cout << "name from aceobj :" << aceobj.getName() <<endl;

    AcetoAcmeAdapter ace2acme(aceobj);

    cout << "First_name from ace2acme :" << ace2acme.getFirstName() << endl;
    cout << "Last_name from ace2acme :" << ace2acme.getLastName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor things:

1. Don't use `using namespace std`. Read
   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
2. When you are naming variables, keep it consistent. Either stick with
   `camelCase` or `underscore`.
3. For the inline functions, keep it on one line. It's easier to read.

   ```
   void setName(string n){ name = n; }
   string getName() { return name; }
   ```
4. I would suggest, anything over two lines, define outside of class.
   Particularly the `AcetoAcmeAdapter` constructor.

Comment: Thank you suggestions. from design pattern point of view is this correct way to implement ? because `AcetoAcmeAdapter` redefines functions of the `Acmeclass`, i am bit confused there.

Comment: Well, the functions of `AcmeInterface` are pure virtual methods. When you put these into a class, you do two things. 1. Don't make an object of that class. 2. Override those pure virtual functions. I think from a design pattern POV, what you have is correct.

Comment: The advice to not use `using namespace std;` is not helpful if a person is creating a single-file executable: it is perfectly fine for this.